# boost::log из динамической библиотеки

Tags: c++, linux, boost

Есть проект который состоит из нескольких библиотек. Задумывается так, что все эти библиотеки должны писать в один лог файл. Для этого существует отдельная динамическая библиотека, которая загружается первая, инициализирует boost::log и предоставляет его всем остальным библиотекам. Используется статический boost 1.66.0.

При загрузке библиотеки с boost::log dlopen ругается:

> undefined symbol: _ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix4core20add_global_attributeERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_9attributeE

Это символ находится в библиотеке 'libboost_log.a'. Сама функция в файле /boost_1_66_0/libs/log/src/core.cpp. 'libboost_log.a' линкуется и к бинарю и к библиотеке с логом.
Если не загружать библиотеку с логом как динамическую, а линковать как статическую то всё работает.

Если кто-то с этим сталкивался, подскажите где я туплю.

Comment: А у вас случаем типы `boost::log` не видны в интерфейсе вашей динамической библиотеки?

Comment: Видны. Интерфейс библиотеки возвращает структуру в которой есть boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt.

Comment: Тогда библиотеку `boost::log` следует линковать динамически ко всем исполняемым файлам и библиотекам, которые используют этот интерфейс (включая саму библиотеку)ю

Comment: Или убрать boost::log из интерфейса...
Спасибо за помощь.